# Rails Rspec - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rspec

I have this controller method

```
def dashboard
 method1
 method2
 method3
 ..
end
```

Everything is working fine in `development` environment..
but in `test` environment,
i am getting this error after first few methods.

I checked using `binding.pry` just above the line which i used to get error,

I cannot run any query `eg: Account.first` 
but same `Account.first` works in `dev` environment

Error when i run in `test` environment:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  ORDER BY "accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
from /home/qwinix/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:596:in `async_exec'
```

**Please note the following**

- No erros found in other controllers and respective spec.
- There was no error in the same controller from other branch
- I added few code to `method1`, which executes just fine in both environment. i am getting these error after `method3` which i havent touched.

PS: I did google and search stackoverflow questions, didnt help

Edit: When i moved the `method1` to end, i am not getting any errors, please explain me this behaviour.

Comment: Can you share the actual code where you are getting the error.

Comment: That message means that you had error _before_ that statement and did not roll back transaction, then attempted to execute query that you posted here and postgres complained. You either need to enable auto commit and see what query gives error, use try catch blocks or check your database logs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reset the Test Database?

```
bundle exec rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

or for Rails Version older than 5

```
bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

or shorter:

bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test

Comment: yes, i did try this `bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` same issue.